# How to sort string arrays in C?

Tags: arrays, c

I'm making a program that if a user enters a word (and that's maximum length is 20), then prints the word in alphabetical order.

This code below is that I wrote.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#pragma warning (disable:4996)

#define MAX 20

void bubble_sort(char* arr, int n);

int main(void) {

    char words[MAX];

    int n = sizeof(words) / sizeof(char);

    scanf("%s", words);

    bubble_sort(words, n);

    printf("%s", words);

    return 0;
}

void bubble_sort(char* arr, int n) {

    int i, j, tmp = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
        for(j=0;j<i-1;j++)
            if (*(arr+j) > *(arr+j+1)) {
                tmp = *(arr+j);
                *(arr+j) = *(arr+j+1);
                *(arr+j+1) = tmp;
            }
    }

}
```

But it doesn't work. I used bubble sorting.  I am not skilled to use pointer arrays and sorting, so I can't catch what's wrong.

I'm working on Visual Studio 2019, and it says that return value ignored scanf(). I can't understand. What's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I have Corrected it Check it out...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 20

void bubble_sort(char* arr, int n);

int main(void) {

    char words[MAX];

    scanf("%s", words);
    int n=0;
    /*for(int i=0;i<sizeof(words);i++){
        if(words[i]=='\0'){
            break;
        }
        n++;
    }*/
    
    n=strlen(words); //same as above for loop
    bubble_sort(words, n);

    printf("%s", words);

    return 0;
}

void bubble_sort(char* arr, int n) {

    int i, j, tmp = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for(j=0;j<n-i-1;j++)
            if (*(arr+j) > *(arr+j+1)) {
                tmp = *(arr+j);
                *(arr+j) = *(arr+j+1);
                *(arr+j+1) = tmp;
            }
    }

}
```

Comment: You are correct we can use strlen() there is no problem in that I thought in diffrent perspective sorry for that.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. By the way, I have one more question. What is different from `int n = sizeof(words) / sizeof(char);` and your answer `n=strlen(words);`?

Comment: `int n = sizeof(words) / sizeof(char);` will give `n=20` because `sizeof(words)=20` and `sizeof(char)=1` , But we wanted Total number of character entered in the array so we used `strlen()` function

Comment: Oh I didn't realize it. Thank you soooo much. God bless you.